# Set up Transaction Vs Set up Authorization

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on Paypal integration using paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK, and I didn't understand the difference between Set Up Transaction & Set Up Authorization ?

The two are creating an order and waiting for capture but what's the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

An [authorization transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction-authorize/#) is a type of transaction that authorizes the funds availability at that moment, but does not capture. The capture can be done later, and may or may not succeed.

(Capturing will almost always succeed within the first few days, called the authorization's 'honor period'. Within the rest of the first 29 days, it may succeed and is roughly equivalent to a new transaction being attempted. After 29 days, authorizations expires.)

You can reed abut authorization and capture here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/auth-capture/

Never use authorizations unless you have extremely specific and well-defined business reasons for doing so.

Comment: you want to say by "authorizes the funds availability at that moment" that it checks if the user's account has money equal/more than the order amount, and if OK, it's create an order. 
So you want to say that transaction required a capture in a few minutes and if the user didn't capture, the order will be deleted. 
But authorization waits a month before deleting the order.
That's correct ?

Comment: It doesn't create an order, the order was already created. It completes an order with an authorization transaction. The authorization transaction will expire after 29 days if not captured.

Comment: I'am a beginner in payment trade but I start understanding, So there is two alternative to create an order, based on intent property :  'intent' => 'CAPTURE' | 'AUTHORIZE', SO order of type CAPTURE required to be captured in a few minutes ? that's true ?

Comment: Orders should be used as soon as possible, always create a new one if needed -- but the actual expiration time is maybe something like 48 or 72 hours after creation and 3 hours after approval

Comment: Ok we are agree at this point, Now we come to Authorization, So there is an Order that has the intent = "AUTHORIZE", So what's the difference between this Order and the Order that has the intent = 'CAPTURE' ?

Comment: One is for capturing. The other is for authorizing and then capturing.

Comment: Ok, a last question : what is the meaning of authorizing an already created order ? ( authorizing means allowing, what we are allowing here with the order ? )

Comment: An order is created the moment it comes into existence. There is nothing special about a created order.  Payers approve orders, that is the 'allow' action on orders. Authorizations are not an allow action, they are a transaction type that checks for fund availability and so complete an order.